# Advantages of Discrete Control in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to understand the difference between Discrete and Continuous control algorithms in RL, and from what I've been able to tell it's that Discrete Control methods seem to predict *one hot encoded vectors* and Continuous control methods output continuous values that can be used to achieve a *softmax-like* functionality.

If this understanding is correct, than what is the advantage of ever using Discrete control algorithms, when you can just use an `argmax` on the output of a Continuous control algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to output a continuous variable between 0 and 1 when the agent might be able to take only 2 possible actions, such as going right (action 0) or going left (action 1)?